# Django form not showing

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to create a form in Django but it is not showing in the browser

views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .forms import FormularioRegistro

def registro(request):
     form= FormularioRegistro()

     return render(request,'Proyecto_RapiExpress_App/registro.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```py
from django import forms


class FormularioRegistro(forms.Form):    
    Nombre=forms.CharField(label= "Titulo", required=True),
    Apellido1=forms.CharField(label= "Primer Apellido", required=True),
    Appelido2=forms.CharField(label= "Segundo Apellido", required=True),
    Telefono=forms.CharField(label= "Telefono", required=True, widget=forms.NumberInput),
    Cedula=forms.CharField(label= "Cedula", required=True, widget=forms.NumberInput),
    email=forms.EmailField(label= "Email", required=True),
    contrasena=forms.CharField(label= "Email", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput),
```

registro.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}

    Registro
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="" method="post">
        <div>{{form}}</div>
    </form>
    
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: -Did you check already the path of your html? 
-did you config the naming of your template directories in settings.py?

Comment: -Did you check already the path of your HTML? Yes I did actually if I edit something in the HTML it is showing but it is not just showing the form

Comment: It seems you haven't pasted the correct `forms.py` code

Comment: You posted views.py in forms.py. Both are same files.

Comment: Sorry, I just pasted the correct forms.py

Comment: @FrancedLatouche Does it is also not showing in source code? See it through ctrl+U, then try to restart the server in another port through `python manage.py runserver 3000`.

Comment: Did you ran makemigrations and migrate ??, did you registered it in admin ?? check if it showing in admin site !

Answer (score 0):

First, try to restart the server and if it doesn't work, try to structure your view function like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .forms import FormularioRegistro

def registro(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= FormularioRegistro()

context = {'form': form}
return render(request,'Proyecto_RapiExpress_App/registro.html', context)
```